# stopping device to enter sleep mode for a duration of time

Tags: ios, ipad, uiapplicationdelegate

In my application i have some content to be downloaded from a server and when the user starts a download and the app is in-active state the app is going into background state where the downloads are getting stopped and failed.In order to avoid this i tried implementing download continuation in background using "**beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler**".This is working only for a certain of period of time and if the device is in background state/sleep mode  for longer time,the downloads are getting failed.

In order to avoid the failing of downloads i thought of avoiding the device going into sleep mode while application is downloading content and implemented the same.

I have set the setIdleTimerDisabled to YES as soon as the download is started and reverted the property to NO after completion of download or failure of download.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:Yes];
```

The application is restricted in going to sleep mode after a download is started but after completion of dowload,still the application is not going into sleep mode.

After a download is initated the application would never go to sleep mode.

Can some one help me in restricting the device to sleep only during the dowmload is happening.

TNQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem on resetting screen brightness. From my research i found that after pressing home button OS take over the control and wont allow you to reset brightness,timer, etc.

You can solve this problem in another way.Provide a local notification on download completed and in applicationWillEnterForeground write your code to enable timer

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
}
```

I got this from StackOverflow, but I forgot the link. Sorry.

Comment: In my case i am not pressing home button but still the application never goes to sleep after setting idleTimmerDisabled propertty to NO.after completion of download i am setting the property to NO and as there is no interaction with the device the device should go into sleep...plz suggest if u have any more info

Comment: i will also try implementing the logic u said above,local notification in the sense u mean NSNotification?am i correct..

Comment: I used UILocalNotification,I think there will be some other problem in your code since you are not pressing the home button and you cant reset idle timer.Check whether the delegates are properly set.Pls post your code if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: tnx for the reply Arshad,what delegate should i set.there is nothing new i have done in my code.-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{    // i am setting the idleTimerDisabled to Yes}.and in connection didFinishLoading i am setting the same to NO.but it doesn't go to sleep after completion of download.The device property is being changed.even though my app is in background and i switch to other app even then the device doesn't go to sleep.i tried resetting the time duration in settings tab of ipad but the ipad never sleeps from  then on.

Comment: Arshad@tnx for all the help.Finally i solved my issue.All these i have been testing my app while it is connected to xcode (debugging),fortunately when i disconnected the ipad from mac and tested everything seemed working.I am not yet sure what happened when it is connected to xcode...funny things happen